# How to pass immutable parameters to a thread? (about lifetimes)

Tags: multithreading, rust, lifetime

Let thread state consists of immutable parameters `Params` and the rest of the (mutable) state `State`.

I am trying to mock spawning a thread that does something being controlled by parameters `Params`:

```rust
use std::thread;

struct Params {
    x: i32,
}

struct State<'a> {
    params: &'a Params,
    y: i32,
}

impl<'a> State<'a> {
    fn new(params: &Params) -> State {
        State {
            params,
            y: 0,
        }
    }
    fn start(&mut self) -> thread::JoinHandle<()> {
        let params = self.params.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || { params; /* ... */ })
    }
}
```

But this does not work:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
  --> test.rs:20:34
   |
20 |         let params = self.params.clone();
   |                                  ^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime `'a` as defined on the impl at 12:6...
  --> test.rs:12:6
   |
12 | impl<'a> State<'a> {
   |      ^^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> test.rs:20:34
   |
20 |         let params = self.params.clone();
   |                                  ^^^^^
   = note: expected  `&&Params`
              found  `&&'a Params`
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that the type `[closure@test.rs:21:23: 21:42 params:&Params]` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> test.rs:21:9
   |
21 |         thread::spawn(move || { params; /* ... */ })
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I understand why it does not work: The thread could run indefinitely long, and the `params` could be destroyed before it is terminated. That's clearly an error.

Now explain what is the proper way to make `params` long at least as long as the thread. In other words, help to correct the above code. What should I do with lifetimes?

Answer (score 1):

You got the right idea with using `clone` and a `move` lambda, but you forgot one detail: `Params` isn't `Clone`! Therefore the compiler did the best it could when it saw `self.params.clone()` and cloned… the reference.

That's why the error messages have two `&` here:

```
   = note: expected  `&&Params`
              found  `&&'a Params`
```

Your issue is solved by [using `#[derive(Clone)] struct Params { /* … */ }`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4bd61d6fbccdf101d96844e62a81a5b1).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I modified my code a little and it does not work again: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63767107/856090