# Revisited: How to pass immutable parameters to a thread? (about lifetimes)

Tags: multithreading, rust, lifetime

[This my question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63766559/856090) was answered.

But when I modified the code a little, it does not work again with a compilation error similar to the error in the previous question. What is my error now?

```rust
use std::thread;

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Params<'a> {
    x: &'a i32,
}

struct State<'a> {
    params: &'a Params<'a>,
    y: i32,
}

impl<'a> State<'a> {
    fn new(params: &'a Params<'a>) -> Self {
        State {
            params,
            y: 0,
        }
    }
    fn start(&mut self) -> thread::JoinHandle<()> {
        let params = self.params.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || { params; /* ... */ })
    }
}
```

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/lib.rs:21:34
   |
21 |         let params = self.params.clone();
   |                                  ^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime `'a` as defined on the impl at 13:6...
  --> src/lib.rs:13:6
   |
13 | impl<'a> State<'a> {
   |      ^^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> src/lib.rs:21:34
   |
21 |         let params = self.params.clone();
   |                                  ^^^^^
   = note: expected `&Params<'_>`
              found `&Params<'a>`
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that the type `[closure@src/lib.rs:22:23: 22:52 params:Params<'_>]` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> src/lib.rs:22:9
   |
22 |         thread::spawn(move || { params; /* ... */ })
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Do you have to have a method called `start()` that just starts the work? Would having a method like `run(f: F)` work for you, with `F` being a closure, so that you can call it with `state.run(|| some code here)`? Because, if so, there is a (safe) way to have thread access data that contains references.

Comment: @user4815162342 Your way is possible in principle, but I want to avoid it, because it means that I would need to write the closure in the calling code, instead of incapsulating it in a separate module. That is, this would break incapsulating, or do I misunderstand you?

Comment: I _think_ you misunderstood me, but I'm not positive. What I'm askinng is whether it's acceptable that instead of `state.start(); foo...; state.join()` you write `state.run(|| foo...)`. The "foo" is at the caller's site in **both** cases, so encapsulation is not broken - but the latter is still a bit more limiting.

Comment: @user4815162342 That's impossible in my real code: I have several threads that I need to run simultaneously.

Comment: Then I think you'll need to replace the reference with an `Arc`, as suggested by kurbaniec.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using references I would suggest using a reference counted type (Arc), that way you do not need to worry about lifetimes.

```rust
use std::thread;
use std::sync::Arc;

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Params {
    x: i32,
}

struct State {
    params: Arc<Params>,
    y: i32,
}

impl State {
    fn new(params: &Arc<Params>) -> Self {
        State {
            params: params.clone(),
            y: 0,
        }
    }
    fn start(&self) -> thread::JoinHandle<()> {
        let params = self.params.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || { params; /* ... */ })
    }
}
```

If you want to mutate the state later on, you would need to wrap the `Params` type in the `State` struct with a Mutex like `Arc<Mutex<Params>>`.

More on the topic:

- [Rc, the Reference Counted Smart Pointer](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-04-rc.html)
- [Shared-State Concurrency](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch16-03-shared-state.html)
- [Arc-Docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html)

Comment: You haven't answered why my code produces an error.

Comment: The code has a reference `x: &'a i32` in `Params`. So `Params` need to have a lifetime specifier anyway, even if using reference counting. So, please edit your answer to correct the type of `x`, it must be a reference.

Comment: I think that a reference in this context is not possible. Your code errors because the struct Params has not a static lifetime, therefore it cannot guarantee that the reference it has is still valid when the thread runs. [Here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/share-reference-across-threads/895/4) you can find a similar discussion with the same conclusion and some better explanations.